# I need to automate the application on andorid to order a taxi

Tags: python, android, automation, appium, telegram

I am writing a program for automatic taxi booking in Yandex.Taxi (local Uber)
through the telegram bot.

I had some difficulties on my way to a working program

1. Yandex.Taxi has a version in the browser, initially I wanted to use Selenium and Python to order a taxi, but in the browser I can only order two cities, Moscow and St. Petersburg
   in the rest it says a request error (Probably some protection) because of this, I decided to try to automate the Yandex.Taxi application in android using the Nox Player emulator
2. I decided to use the Android SDK Build Tools and Appium and Python to automate the actions on the emulator.
   Using the emulator I encountered new problems

   2.1 How to put all this on the server?

   2.2 How to simultaneously connect Appium to several
   copies of the emulator?

2.3 How to find out or specify port for new instances of a class
Do you have Nox Player?
In the first instance, port = 62001. When experimenting, I found out that the following ports for new instances start from 62025 -... will this trend continue on other machines?

2.4 Did I choose Appium for automation?
2.5 Did I choose Nox Player for emulators correctly?

I will be glad to hear your suggestions, how and what to use in order to automate the work of my bot

Comment: This is far too broad/vague, and as such also off topic for Stack Overflow. See: [help/on-topic], [ask].

Comment: you need to start an appium course xd